# Раскрывающиеся по клику блоки

Tags: javascript

Имеется блок картинок. По 3 в строке. Бесконечный, генерирующийся `foreach`. Нужно чтобы при клике на любую из картинок, снизу этой картинки выезжал блок с описанием(аля гугл-картинки), при этом сдвигая блоки самих картинок вниз. При клике на следующую, предыдущее описание должно скрываться. 
Т.к. блок с описанием на всю ширину, а картинка на треть, блок с описанием имеет `position:absolute`. В следствии чего не сдвигает картинки вниз, а появляется поверх. Для выхода из положения был добавлен `toggleClass` с `margin-bottom` для картинки. Сейчас происходит чехарда и `toggleClass` отрабатывает нестабильно. Может есть решение этой проблемы? Или другой рабочий метод.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1" >
  <div class="programm-item">
   //блок с картинкой
  </div>                   
</div>  
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием
 </div>   
</div>
```

Появление блока с описанием

```
<script>
$(function(){
    //скрываю все блоки с описанием
    $('.hiden').hide();
    $a = $('.view-source .programm-item');
    $a.on('click', function(event) {
      //при клике открываю соответствующий блок
      event.preventDefault();
      $a.not(this).next().slideUp(0);
      $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
   });
});
</script>
```

Добавление класса в зависимости от `rel`. Т.к. блоки генерируются, какому `rel` присвоить класс выясняю методом целочисленного деления.

```
 c= $('div[rel]'); 


  c.each(function() {
  $('.view-source').click(function(){
  f= $(this).attr('rel');  

  if ( f%3 == 0) {  //3
  $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').toggleClass('tp').prevAll('.view-source').removeClass('tp');
  $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').nextAll('.view-source').removeClass('tp');
}

    if ( f%3 == 2) {  //2
    $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').prevAll('.view-source').removeClass('tp');

    f = parseInt(f)+1; //3
    $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').nextAll('.view-source').removeClass('tp');
    $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').toggleClass('tp');

}
    if ( f%3 == 1) {  //1
    $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').prevAll('.view-source').removeClass('tp');

    f = parseInt(f)+2;  //3
    $('div[rel="'+f+'"]').toggleClass('tp');
}
});
});
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скрипт группирует описание по три подряд, три картинки, затем три описания, показ описания выбирается по индексу картинки.

```js
$(function() {
    var b = $(".row.hiden"),
        d = $(".view-source"),
        a;
    b.each(function(b, c) {
        b % 3 - 2 ? a = a ? a.add($(c)) : $(c) : (a && a.insertBefore($(c)), a = null)
    });
    d.on("click", function() {
        var a = d.index(this);
        b.not(b.eq(a).slideToggle()).slideUp()
    })
});
```

```css
.view-source {
   width: 33%;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #0000FF;
   float: left;
 }
 .row.hiden {
   width: 99%;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #FF0000;
   display: none;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 6
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  view-source" rel="1">
  <div class="programm-item">
    //блок с картинкой
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ============= -->
<div class="row hiden">
  <div class="col-xs-12 programm-details-item ">
    //блок с описанием 7
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вариант хороший и рабочий. Но адаптив, к сожалению, не работает.

Comment: @DmitryN, а что такое адаптив? может css ваше добавите

Comment: Все, Рони, спасибо! Я поправил скрипт под другие экраны.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код не сохранил, но задачка решается к примеру так. Но это банальный пример, все зависит от кучи факторов, резины макета, и тд.

```js
  $(function(){
   $('.items').on('click', '.item', function(event) {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var eq = 0;

    if (index % 3 == 0 ) {
     eq = index + 2;
    } else if (index % 3 == 1 ) {
     eq = index + 1;
    } else if (index % 3 == 2 ) {
     eq = index;
    }

    $('.extra-wrapper').remove();
    $('.item').eq(eq).after('<div class="extra-wrapper"></div>');
    $('.extra-wrapper').text('img-index-' + $(this).index());
   });
  });
```

```css
  * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .items {
   width: 495px;
  }
  .item {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  }

  .extra-wrapper {
   background: tomato none repeat scroll 0 0;
   float: left;
   padding: 15px;
   width: calc(100%  - 5px);
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   height: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="items">
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img src="http://dummyimage.com/160x120/000000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
```